# Too many connections on QGIS using PostGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to execute some queries on QGIS connected to a PostGIS. However, I'm receiving the error 'too many connections', on my company each user can only use **one** connection. I've searched on manual, but I did not find how to configure the maximum of connection on QGIS.

Comment: I think it may have something to do with your database tuning this link might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778015/how-to-increase-the-max-connections-in-postgres and have a read of https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server for more info.